# How to bind data to a kendoui grid from an ajax query?

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I have a datepicker and a grid on a page. I want the grid to be populated based on the date in the datepicker. I have done this with a Telerik mvc grid using grid.dataBind.

```
var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
var pDate = document.getElementById('DatePicker').value;
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Home/AccountSummary/',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { date: pDate },
  success: function (result) {
    grid.dataBind(result);
  }
});
```

Now I want to do the same thing except with the Kendoui grid. I know I need to get the grid by using `$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid')`. But how do I bind my result to the grid?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming the result variable contains an array of javascript objects, and it contains data for the same number of columns as the original mark up.

ie. `result = [{"AccountId":1,"Name":"AAA"},{"AccountId":2,"Name":"BBB"}];`

Try the following:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/AccountSummary/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { date: pDate },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I add the line $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.fetch(); right after dataSource.data(result), this works for me. For some reason, it doesn't work without fetch(). Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have any event listeners associated with the grid? Could they be preventing something? Assigning new data actually refreshes the whole grid, if you step through kendo.web.js you will see exactly what happens. For a refresh you can try calling either fetch or read functions on the datasource.

Comment: @Daniel - the fetch statement is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Igorrious in this way kendo date time format is not working how to solve that??

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it this way:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Controller/Handler",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({key: "value"}),
                success: function(data) {
                    options.success(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then bind it to the grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource
}
```

This way you can add the rest of the CRUD actions to your transport and you will have all your code in one place.

Comment: This solution is great if you need server-side paging, which requires the transport ajax approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind Json results to the grid.  And also you can pass Model if you need to.  See the code snippet below for example.

See [here](http://kirandhappuri.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/kendo-ui-window-a-modal-dialog-with-kendo-grid-mvc-controller-action-partial-view-and-ajax-calls-to-refresh-data/) for more details.

```
$('#FindBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var UserDetails =
    {
        "FirstName": document.getElementById('FirstName').value,
        "LastName": document.getElementById('LastName').value,
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "SearchJsonRequest",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(UserDetails),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var grid = $('#AssociateSearch').getKendoGrid();
            grid.dataSource.data(data);
            grid.refresh();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Igorrious... That exact answer didn't help me but it lead me to an answer.

What worked for me:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    data: {
      paramKey: paramValue
    },
    success: function (result) {
      $("#my-grid").data("tGrid").dataBind(result);
    }
});
```

If this doesn't help you, do some javascript debugging to find out why some of the elements in chain `[$("#my-grid")] . [data("tGrid")] . [dataBind]` have `value == 'undefined'`.

Comment: Tnx. I removed it, but couldn't find another to replace it... :(